# Rails 3 after_initialize not running when create is called with a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to set some default values for an object using `after_initialize`. The problem I am having is that I would like this to be called no matter how the object is created.

My class:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  serialize :data

  after_initialize :init

  def init
    self.data ||= {}
    self.bar ||= "bar"
    self.baz ||= "baz"
  end

end
```

Everything works fine if I call `Foo.new`, `Foo.new(:bar => "things")` and `Foo.create(:baz => 'stuff')`.  However when I use a block with `create` the `after_initialize` callback doesn't get run.

```
obj = Foo.create do |f|
  f.bar = "words"
  f.data = { :attr_1 => 1, :attr_2 => 2 }
end
```

This just yields `obj.baz` => `nil` instead of `"baz"` with the other attributes set correctly.

Am I missing something with the way callbacks are executed, with the differences with calling create with a block and without or are default values getting clobbered by the block?

**UPDATE**

Found the issue.

It turns out that calling `create` with block and without are subtly different.  When you call `create` without a block and just pass in a hash of parameters, for all intents and purposes you are calling `Foo.new({<hash of argument>}).save`, and the `after_initialize` callback gets executed right before the save like you would expect.

When you call `create` with a block something a little different happens.  The order of events is `Foo.new` is called with whatever arguments you pass in, then `after_initialize` gets called, then the block gets run.  So if you are using the block (as I was) interchangeably with the hash parameters just to make things a little bit more readable you could get bit because your `after_initialize` is run before all of the parameters you intend to set are actually set.

I got bit because I was doing some extra work in the `after_initialize` setting some extra required attributes based on the value of what was getting passed.  Since nothing was actually set when `after_initialize` got called, nothing got set correctly and my validations failed.

I ended up having to make to calls to `init`.  Once on `after_initialize` and once on `before_validation`.  Not the cleanest, but it solved the issue.

Thanks go to Brandon for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you do the same thing but with `Foo.new` (i.e. with the block method of declaration), does the same thing happen?

Comment: Foo.new with a block works just fine.

Comment: @HMCFletch - great explanation of what's happening - thanks for sharing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this. I happen to have an application handy with the following (simplified) class:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize        :data, Hash
  after_initialize :create_default_data
  attr_accessible  :data, :token

  protected

    def create_default_data
      self.data ||= Hash.new
    end
end
```

Here's an IRB session:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > obj = Service.create do |s|
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 >     s.token = "abc"
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003?>   end
 => #<Service id: 22, user_id: nil, type: nil, data: {}, created_at: "2011-03-05 04:18:00", updated_at: "2011-03-05 04:18:00", token: "abc"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004 > obj.data
 => {}
```

As you can see, `data` as initialized in the `after_initialize` method to an empty hash. The Rails code indicates this makes sense as well; in `create`:

```
def create(attributes = nil, &block)
  if attributes.is_a?(Array)
    attributes.collect { |attr| create(attr, &block) }
  else
    object = new(attributes)
    yield(object) if block_given?
    object.save
    object
  end
end
```

So `create` calls `new` and assigns the value to `object` before it `yield`s. Here's the relevant part in `new`:

```
def initialize(attributes = nil)
  # truncated for space
  result = yield self if block_given?
  run_callbacks :initialize
  result
end
```

As you can see, `new` unconditionally calls the `initialize` callbacks before it returns, and thus before `create` even yields to the block you pass. **By the time your block gets the object, the `after_initialize` method has already executed**.

Double check that (1) your version of Rails is up to date (3.0.5 as of now I believe) and that (2) nothing is setting `baz` without you realizing it.

Comment: Thanks for the piece in bold.  That was exactly what was causing my problems.  I wrote up a little explanation at the bottom of my question detailing what was happening.  Thanks, for the help.

Comment: Very interesting, and great that you nailed down what was going on. I can't imagine you are the only person to ever be bitten by this...